# React Router Redux Immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js, react-router-redux

Been using [this](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) boilerplate for a while and have been using plain JS objects as the store/state up until I started getting some odd mutations randomly so decided to switch to Immutable.js. Currently I'm trying to implement [redux-immutable](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable) into my code. I'm having some issue with react-router-redux and redux-immutable; unfortunately I don't know these libraries very well 'under-the-hood' so having a lot of trouble debugging this. I have followed the instructions in the redux-immutable README on this.

Getting this error in my index.js file.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJS' of undefined

**index.js**

```
const initialState = Immutable.Map({});

const store = configureStore(initialState);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState (state) {
    return state.getIn([
      'route',
      'location'
    ]).toJS();
  }
});

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**configureStore.js**

```
const router = routerMiddleware(hashHistory);

const enhancer = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk, router, logger),
  DevTools.instrument(),
  persistState(
    window.location.href.match(
      /[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/
    )
  )
);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer);

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () =>
      store.replaceReducer(require('../reducers'))
    );
  }

  return store;
}
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux-immutable';

import routing from './Routing';
import Graphing from './Graphing';
import Syncing from './Syncing';
import Navigating from './Navigating';
import Notifying from './Notifying';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  routing,
  Graphing,
  Navigating,
  Syncing,
  Notifying
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**routing.js (routing reducer)**

```
import {LOCATION_CHANGE} from 'react-router-redux';

const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  location: {}
});

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOCATION_CHANGE) {
    return state.merge({
      location: action.payload
    });
  }

  return state;
};
```

Comment: can you try with `return state.getIn([
      'routing',
      'location'
    ]).toJS();` instead of  `return state.getIn([
      'route',
      'location'
    ]).toJS();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation it's suggested to use `routing` as the reducer key. So here you are basically trying to access the store with the key `routing` instead of `route`

I just tried it without immutable, and is as below,

```
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState(state) {
    console.log(state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions);
    return state.routing;
  }
});
```

This will return,
[image]

Hope it helps